# Using EVAL and REGEX in iMacros to EXTRACT characters

Tags: javascript, regex, eval, imacros

Let's say I have:

```
SET !EXTRACT "this is a Make of the car"
```

If I use:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.match(\"Make\"); ")
```

then I get a prompt "Make". Now, let's say I'm interested in the phrase " a Make of the ". According to online tester (http://www.regexr.com/), regex would be:

```
(?<=this is)(.*)(?=car)
```

However, the below code doesn't work:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.match(\"(?<=this is)(.*)(?=car)\"); ")
```

I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: invalid quantifier, line 16 (Error code: -1001)

Why?

EDIT: Apparently, using other online tester (http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm), regex should be:

```
(?![this is])(.*)(?=car)
```

However, by using this:

```
SET !VAR2 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.match(\"(?![this is])(.*)(?=car)\"); ")
```

I get

> a Make of the ,a Make of the

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not good at regex but this is interesting question. I ask for regex solutions on stackoverflow chat. Channel JavaScript.

Comment: iMacros has built-in function 'SEARCH' for this purpose: http://wiki.imacros.net/SEARCH

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue and came across this question when trying to figure out what was happening. Took me some time to figure out what was going on. Pardon me if I'm not using the proper terminology.

Let me use your last example to explain what is happening.

```
SET !VAR2 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.match(\"(?![this is])(.*)(?=car)\"); ")
```

The reason that you're getting the output:

```
a Make of the ,a Make of the
```

is because the parenthesis in the regex is storing the matching data in a separate array in the "s" variable, which is what is coming after the comma. By specifying which array that contains the data you want "s" to output, you can get the output you're looking for.

For example, if you wanted:

```
a Make of the
```

as the desired output, use

```
SET !VAR2 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.match(\"(?![this is])(.*)(?=car)\"); s[0];")
```

Observe the "s[0]" towards the end of this line. The [0] array translates to "everything that is being matched", where [1] is "everything that is matched in the (first) parenthesis". Don't ask me why it works like this. I came across the following forum thread that pointed me in the right direction.

http://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=18938

Since I came across this question before that forum post, I thought I'd share what I figured out here in case anyone else runs into the same situation.